# BLE library for Beetle Bluno BLE with AVR architecture (ATmega328)

Tags: bluetooth, ble, bluno

When I try to `#include <ArduinoBLE.h>` in my Arduino program, I get the error:

> WARNING: library ArduinoBLE claims to run on samd, megaavr, mbed, apollo3, mbed_nano, mbed_portenta architecture(s) and may be incompatible with your current board which runs on avr architecture(s).

Apart from potentially trying to import an incompatible library, am I doing something wrong? If not, are there any Arduino libraries for AVR architectures that will allow me to transfer data through Bluetooth via dealing with Services, Characteristics, Descriptors, etc.?

The [Beetle Bluno BLE](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Bluno_Beetle_SKU_DFR0339) board is based on:

- ICSP1: ATmega 328P
- ICSP2: CC2540

Comment: ArduinoBLE is not compatible with CC2540. the CC2540 on Bluno Beetle has AT commands

Comment: @Juraj thanks, how can AT commands help me here?

Answer (score 0):

The device is not an Arduino device (Uno, Mega, Nano, Mkr, etc) and ArduinoBLE was made only for Arduino devices with built-in Bluetooth.

Comment: it is an Arduino, just the BLE IC is not supported by the ArduinoBLE library